# ACR122U idle/decection LED state

Tags: android, led, apdu, smartcard-reader, acr122

Is there any APDU command that could control LED state of PRESENT/ABSENT reader states? (eventually for any other state)

For this purpose there are only buzzer linked commands in the [API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fyCS.png).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in [chapter 6.2 (page 22)](http://downloads.acs.com.hk/drivers/en/API-ACR122U-2.02.pdf) is described how to control the led. In appendix E are some examples.

You have to send commands like this:

```
0xFF, 0x00, 0x40, LED state, 0x04, data
```

Which value must be used for the LED state and the data is described in tables "P2" and "Data In" at page 22.

Comment: If I execute command that should result in orange color when the card is detached it always gets orange but just for a while and then turns red. I want the LED to stay orange.